# How do I get a footer to appear at bottom of window

Tags: web-development, website-design

I am doing a new site and I need a footer area to appear at the bottom of the content (much like this site), but I want it to appear at the bottom of the window when there is less content than requires a scrollbar.

For example:
http://odata.stackexchange.com/

...has a footer, but on a large screen it appears in the middle of the page. I want it to attach to the bottom of the window but geet there is more text in which case it floats beneath the content.

I hope I have described my problem sufficiently :-)

Does anyone have any ideas or help with this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The best tutorial I know about it: http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/keeping-footers-at-the-bottom-of-the-page

Comment: yw Dan, I think you will enjoy almost all articles from Matthew James Taylor for webdesign.

Answer (score 1):

You'll be after [CSS fixed position](http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_class_position.asp) -  `position: fixed` and `bottom: 0`, [for example](http://jsfiddle.net/jP5WT/).

Comment: Just keep in mind IE6 (and maybe 7, not sure) don't support fixed positioning so they won't see the footer at the bottom of the page.

Comment: Unfortunately, that is not what I am after as the text scrolls underneath it when the content is longer than viewable. I need the text to always push the footer to the end